# SQL parent child table query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, one-to-many, relation

I have two tables: parent and child.

Parent table has columns `Pid`,  `Pname` and  `Pgroup`

Child table has columns `Cid`,    `Pid`

I need an sql query to count number of child rows with `Pgroup = 1`.

Comment: I have written a query like                                      SELECT COUNT(cid) FROM child c JOIN parent p WHERE c.Pid=p.Pid AND p.Pgroup=1.                                                          Is it correct or what is wrong or how to improve it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from parent p
join child c
on p.pid = c.pid
where p.pgroup = 1
```

If you want to do it without a join you can use a subquery.

```
select count(*)
from child c
where c.pid in (select pid from parent p where pgroup = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, can we do it without using join like by nesting plz.